# phonegap ajax request not working in http

Tags: android, ajax, phonegap

I'm building an android app with PhoneGap and I have a button that triggers an ajax http POST request.
Seems that it works in https but doesn't work in http (the "error" callback function of the ajax request is triggered without any relevant info). 
In order to test it I've used the utility https://cors-test.appspot.com/ that returns a dummy message with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header in order to manage CORS requests. NB: the utility supports both http and https requests.
What could be the reason of the failure?
The log in the Android Studio (I'm testing it through the device simulator (Google Pixel 2)) console doesn't highlight any warning/error and are identical in both working (https) and not working (http) case:

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 25 : http://cors-test.appspot.com/test
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "http://cors-test.appspot.com/test", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (25)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 7 4
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 7 8
...
```

I've captured the tcp traffic and in the non-working case (http) the request is not fired at all, so seems that is a PhoneGap/Android configuration issue.
thank you